# How to send email from Terminal?

Tags: bash, email, terminal

I know there are ways to send email from terminal in Linux/MacOS, but I can't seem to find proper documentation on how to do that.

Basically I need it for my bash script that notifies me every time there is a change in a file.

Comment: It should probably be noted here that some hosts and ISPs "turn off" the ability for you to send email. I presume it's an attempt to stop people spamming and phishing through them

Comment: @JimJeffries Which ones? I am using an Amazon EC2 web server.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Go into Terminal and type `man mail` for help.

You will need to set `SMTP` up:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081217161612647

See also:

http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/09/send-mail-over-your-network.html

Eg:

```
mail -s "hello" "example@example.com" <<EOF
hello
world
EOF
```

This will send an email to `example@example.com` with the subject `hello` and the message

> Hello
>
> World

Comment: I just tried, and it worked for me, but I have two questions out of my curiosity.1. What does << means, online I've seen some examples with '<' or '<<. ' What is it used for? And why you have given End Of File there and at the end of the message?

Comment: The "<<EOF" and "EOF" mark a "here-document".  The text between the two EOFs is treated as a multiline quoted string.  It is described in 'man bash'

Answer (score 154):

```
echo "this is the body" | mail -s "this is the subject" "to@address"
```

Comment: Note all this solutions assume you have a locally installed MTA

Comment: @Miquel good point.  In Ubuntu, you can get the prerequisites via `sudo apt-get install mailutils`.

Comment: @James, It isn't work for my MAC((( Could you help me?

Comment: Step by step tutorial: http://rianjs.net/2013/08/send-email-from-linux-server-using-gmail-and-ubuntu-two-factor-authentication

Comment: Strange. This gives me a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" message although the only change that I have made was changing the address.

Comment: MTA is mail transfer agent btw. which mean you have to set up mail server before you run the command.

Answer (score 89):

Probably the simplest way is to use `curl` for this, there is no need to install any additional packages and it can be configured directly in a request.

Here is an example using gmail smtp server:

```
curl --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' --ssl-reqd \
  --mail-from 'from-email@gmail.com' \
  --mail-rcpt 'to-email@gmail.com' \
  --user 'from-email@gmail.com:YourPassword' \
  -T <(echo -e 'From: from-email@gmail.com\nTo: to-email@gmail.com\nSubject: Curl Test\n\nHello')
```

Comment: This is a really good option. You can generate an app specific password for your Google account and this just delivers the email from your own account. Very cool!

Comment: @aliaksandr should add this last point to his answer. By default this option (give access to less secure apps) is disabled and it's not evident. At least if you're using gmail account as sender email.

Comment: Very nice. Curl is another awesome swiss army knife like netcat :)

Comment: How would you attach a file with this method?

Comment: Didn't work for me, it printed this `curl: (67) Login denied`

Comment: Note that this will only work for Gmail accounts when using app passwords (less secure apps is no longer a thing). https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Here's how you get that App Password in 2023: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 42):

If all you need is a subject line (as in an alert message) simply do:

```
mailx -s "This is all she wrote" < /dev/null "myself@myaddress"
```

Comment: You may need to install `mailutils`. It can be installed via a package manager (eg. `apt install mailutils`)

Answer (score 23):

If you want to attach a file on Linux

```
echo 'mail content' | mailx -s 'email subject' -a attachment.txt username@stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: It gives an `invalid header` message for my attached file. The correct option was an uppercase `-A`.

Comment: @Stephane According to patrick-haugh, -a is the attachment switch. -A is for the account command. See the man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx

Answer (score 8):

in the terminal on your mac os or linux os type this code

```
mail -s (subject) (receiversEmailAddress)  <<< "how are you?"
```

for an example try this

```
mail -s "hi" abc@example.com <<< "how are you?"<br>
```

Comment: Probably an unimportant nit, but it is not sufficient to do this "in the terminal".  Many times when you are typing "in the terminal" you are not typing commands that will be executed by a shell, and this solution will only work if you type the above as input to a shell.

Answer (score 7):

For SMTP hosts and Gmail I like to use Swaks -> https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mail/swaks-smtp-test-tool/

On a Mac:

1. `brew install swaks`
2. `swaks --to user@example.com --server smtp.example.com`

Answer (score 2):

I think swaks is the best. Here you have more complicated example, using TLS encryption on port 25:

```
swaks --from john.smith@mydomain.com \
--h-From: '"John Smith" <john.smith@mydomain.com>' \
--h-Subject: 'Subject of message' \
--auth LOGIN --auth-user mylogin --auth-pass mypass \
--to someone@otherdomain.com \
--server smtp.example.com --port 25 -tls \
--add-header 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"'
```

Comment: Got `*** TLS not available: requires Net::SSLeay.  Exiting`. Any ides how to fix? UPD: [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55960237/1778275).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send a multiline message using `mailx` with the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

MSG_FROM=zac@server.it
MSG_TO="zac@gmail.com"
MSG_SUBJ="Test"
SMTP_HOST="relay.zac.it"
MSG_BODY=(
"Line one" 
"" 
"Line two")

printf '%s\n' "${MSG_BODY[@]}" | mailx -v -s "$MSG_SUBJ" -S smtp="smtp://$SMTP_HOST" -S from=$MSG_FROM $MSG_TO
```

I am under Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)