# install perl module Net::SSLeay through cpan

Tags: perl, email, openssl, sendmail, cpan

I have tried to install Net::SSLeay though cpan to install Email::Send::SMTP::TLS but I am getting the following error.

```
cpan[5]> install Net::SSLeay
Running install for module 'Net::SSLeay'
Running make for M/MI/MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.49.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/ubuntu/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.49-VDZ57t
Could not make: Unknown error
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Comment: Try removing first /home/ubuntu/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.49-VDZ57t

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On ubuntu, try

```
sudo apt-get install libnet-ssleay-perl
sudo apt-get install libcrypt-ssleay-perl
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this only works if you're needing Net::SSLeay on your system perl. If you've installed a specific local perl for compatibility or currency reasons the precompiled packages from apt won't help.

Comment: Technically the answer from @jeremyforan is the correct one which answers the question given in the title and works on whatever perl you use

Comment: For me (Debian 8.1) Net::SSLeay just needed libnet-ssleay-perl to build.

Comment: I have installed these libraries, program still say "No TLS support!  SendEmail can't load required libraries. (try installing Net::SSLeay and IO::Socket::SSL)"

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper, you most probably are missing this package 

`sudo apt-get install libio-socket-ssl-perl`.

Comment: This answer is not correct because the question was to install *from CPAN* and this response is more like "don't bother and install from OS binary package instead". It does not cover other cases such as Perlbrew, etc. Most of the issues related to building Net::SSLeay from source (cpan,. cpanm, etc.) are related to missing libssl and libz headers. On Ubuntu, this is generally solved installing libssl-dev and zlib1g-dev and the cpan distribution of Net::SSLeay should build w/o any issues - of course a working C build environment is needed (in Debian/Ubuntu that would be build-essential)

Answer (score 17):

In Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

This resolved the issue for me

Comment: Same for me on Ubuntu Precise

Comment: `yum install openssl-devel` did it for me on CentOS 6.7

Comment: You will generally need zlib1g-dev too (zlib headers)

Answer (score 13):

On Centos, here's my solution:

```
sudo yum install perl perl-CPAN perl-Net-SSLeay perl-IO-Socket-SSL
```

Answer (score 8):

Try running through the process on your own manually. From the CPAN prompt:

1. type `look Net::SSLeay` to go into a shell in the unpacked directory
2. `perl Makefile.PL`
3. `make`
4. `make test`
5. `make install`

If there is a "README" or "INSTALL" file, try reading those too. If you come across any errors, you can append your question and maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

Centos 6.5:

```
yum install perl-Net-SSLeay
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install both dependencies listed below. It should solve the issue that you have.

```
sudo apt-get install libnet-ssleay-perl
sudo apt-get install libio-socket-ssl-perl
```

Comment: This is what I needed when trying to install `LWP::Protocol::https`.

Answer (score 0):

On Arch Linux: `pacman -S perl-net-ssleay`