# Net::SSLeay won't install

Tags: perl, cpan

cpan Net::SSLeay

```
Running install for module 'Net::SSLeay'
Running make for M/MI/MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.55.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.55-v9rgJp
Could not make: Unknown error
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

I have installed all libs of this post:
[install perl module Net::SSLeay through cpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750662/install-perl-module-netssleay-through-cpan?answertab=active#tab-top)

I also tryed to install it manually and during make command I had this log:

```
SSLeay.c:8143: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_BIO_write’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:8110: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_BIO_read’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:8091: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_BIO_free’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:8072: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_BIO_new’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:8053: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_BIO_new_ssl_connect’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:8032: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_BIO_new_ssl’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:8011: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_BIO_new_file’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:7992: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_BIO_new_buffer_ssl_connect’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:7972: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_get_ssl_method’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:7926: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_set_ssl_method’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:7864: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_TLSv1_method’ but no such  parameter
SSLeay.c:1189: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_constant’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:1167: error: declaration for parameter ‘XS_Net__SSLeay_CLONE’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:1123: error: declaration for parameter ‘S_croak_xs_usage’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.xs:422: error: declaration for parameter ‘simple_cb_data_t’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.xs:359: error: declaration for parameter ‘perl_filehandle_t’ but no such parameter
SSLeay.c:13975: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
make: *** [SSLeay.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Please show the *whole* log, not just 10 lines.

Comment: Edited but Stack  has char limits for body question :(

Comment: Put all in a pastebin and link to it, I'll pick out the relevant stuff and edit your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some CPAN modules require the C-header files to compile successfully. They end with `-dev`. These are not normally package with the OS. For `Net::SSLeay` you'll need to install `libssl-dev`.

For Debian distros: `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Comment: sudo yum install `openssl-devel` on CentOS

Comment: you can download openssl sources and install it.