# Perl Dist::Zilla doesn't install because of Net::SSLeay on Debian Wheezy

Tags: perl, debian, perl-module, cpan

I am using [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) together with [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) on debian wheezy.
I tried to install [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla) but installation failed because of `Net::SSLeay`.

Error message: `SSLeay.xs:153:25: fatal error: openssl/err.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden` (German for "openssl/err.h not found").

[People](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999082/netssleay-wont-install) [suggest](http://upasana.me/2013/06/29/problem-installing-in-netssleay/) installing `libssl-dev` which I have already done and does not help.

Is it that something has changed from Squeeze to Wheezy and Perl-Modules are not aware of yet??

Comment: Have you tried `aptitude install libdist-zilla-perl`? Or you must install it with perlbrew/cpanm? I have just installed it like this (with 132 dependencies...) succcessfuly on a fresh wheezy box.

Comment: You mean it was successful with aptitude? Well this is no surprise :-) No it is not a must that I use perlbrew/cpanm, but it is my preferred work-flow.

Comment: Yes, no problems installing with aptitude... Save yourself trouble :)

Comment: Haha, you are joking. This motto was the reason why I switched to perlbrew! "Never mess with your systems Perl" seems logic to me while developing stuff. (but this is offtopic)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it. Here is the complete output of what I did together with complete log of cpanm: http://pastebin.com/TPd44inK , I included output of `perl -V` and `dpkg -l | grep ssl` as well. Anyway: `Successfully installed Net-SSLeay-1.58` && `Successfully installed Dist-Zilla-5.012`.

Comment: Also, what _people suggest_ is correct: `apt-file search /usr/include/openssl/err.h` => `libssl-dev: /usr/include/openssl/err.h`.
Can you post your output of `perl -V` please?

Comment: I managed to reproduce exactly the same error eventually when libssl-dev package was not installed (thus `/usr/include/openssl/err.h` missing), but installing it fixed the issue. Again: please show `perl -V` and complete output of `cpanm -v Net::SSLeay`. There's a `--configure-args` experimental option in cpanm that you might be able to use to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. It seems like the installation of libssl-dev actually failed, and I missed that. OMG http://pastebin.com/njSyHA2J Still need to track down why this happens. Internet works fine. And my Wheezy is a relatively fresh setup. Strange

Comment: Fixed it! `aptitude update` and `aptitude safe-upgrade` brougth updates for `libssl1.0.0 libxfont1 openssl`. After that the installation went fine... If you give me an answer containing this, I'll accept it :-P

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that OpenSSL needs to be compiled into the Perlbrew environment -- the same environment that will run Net::SSLeay.  Try this recipe:

1. Install dependencies:

   `sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall zlib1g-dev -y`
2. Create a subdirectory for OpenSSL under Perlbrew:

   `mkdir ~/perl5/perlbrew/openssl`
3. Download & extract latest LTS OpenSSL into above directory.  To determine latest LTS OpenSSL, go to https://openssl.org/source/ and find the latest stable version.  For example below we use openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz:

   `cd ~/perl5/perlbrew/openssl`

   `wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz  [replace with latest LTS version]`

   `tar -xf openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz`

   `cd openssl-1.1.1`
4. Install and compile. Starting at above directory:

   `./config shared --prefix=$PERLBREW_ROOT/openssl`

   `make`

   `make test`
5. Install Net::SSLeay using cpanm:

   `cpanm install Net::SSLeay`

Comment: This problem is 4 years old and the the solution was found in the comment section below the question. I'm no more capable of reproducing/veryfing anything on this questions. But I hope your answer may help those who come later. thx

Comment: Thank you @yahermann! This procedure was just what I needed to get XML::RPC installed on top of Perl 5.30 running on Perlbrew on Debian Stretch.