# send mail from linux terminal in one line

Tags: linux, email

I know there is the command `mail` in linux to send emails via command line. How can I send an simple email with one line from the terminal though?

For example:

```
mail user@gmail.com [subject] [body]
```

And have the email sent without any confirmation or prompts to the user?

The reason is, I want to send a brief message via email to myself when a specific event happens in a `java` program. The idea is that I will use `Runtime.getRuntime()`… etc. to send the `mail command` from my `java` program.

I used `cron` to do something similar in the past, but the current implementation doesn't use `cron`, so I need to try this out instead.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

**mail** can represent quite a couple of programs on a linux system. What you want behind it is either **sendmail** or **postfix**. I recommend the latter.

You can install it via your favorite package manager. Then you have to configure it, and once you have done that, you can send email like this:

```
 echo "My message" | mail -s subject user@gmail.com
```

See the manual for more information.

As far as configuring postfix goes, there's plenty of articles on the internet on how to do it.
Unless you're on a public server with a registered domain, you generally want to forward the email to a SMTP server that you can send email from.

For gmail, for example, follow
http://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/
or any other similar tutorial.

Comment: Postfix is powerful but if you only need to send email try "ssmtp". This package is smaller and doesn't run a daemon like postfix. It supports secure protocols and works with gmail.

Comment: "The program 'mail' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install mailutils"

Comment: more light-weight: packages `nullmailer` plus `bsd-mailx`. Sufficient for most work-stations :) And as `nullmailer` includes a `sendmail` interface, you might even skip the `bsd-mailx` package and use [Hengjie's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26865403/2533433).

Comment: @oᴉɹǝɥɔ [`ssmtp` is deprecated.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP) Use `msmtp` instead.

Comment: mail -s "Your subject" dunn@mycompany.com <<< "body message goes here." (from source: https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-mail-command#:~:text=Linux%20mail%20command%20is%20a,shell%20scripts%20or%20web%20applications.)

Comment: echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -f FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS -v TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS

Answer (score 41):

```
echo "Subject: test" | /usr/sbin/sendmail user@domain.com
```

This enables you to do it within one command line without having to echo a text file. This answer builds on top of @mti2935's answer. So credit goes there.

Comment: Just to add to the answer for the subject and body: echo -e "Subject: test \n\n Body content here\n" | sendmail user@domain.com

Answer (score 40):

You can use an echo with a pipe to avoid prompts or confirmation.

```
echo "This is the body" | mail -s "This is the subject" user@gmail.com
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8260951/3315914

Answer (score 15):

For Ubuntu users: First You need to install mailutils

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

Setup an email server, if you are using gmail or smtp. follow [this link](https://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-with-gmail-and-ssmtp/). then use this command to send email.

```
echo "this is a test mail" | mail -s "Subject of mail" username@domain.com
```

In case you are using gmail and still you are getting some authentication error then you need to change setting of gmail:

Turn on Access for less secure apps [from here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Answer (score 14):

You can also use sendmail:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail user@domain.com < /file/to/send
```

Comment: Note: I have Postfix+S-Nail . This is what worked for me. First I used "Rohit Gupta" answer and downloaded the mail utilities, then did yours and everything worked.

Answer (score 6):

[You can install the mail package in Ubuntu with below command.](http://gotechnies.com/mail-command/)

For Ubuntu -:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mailutils
```

For CentOs-:

```
$ sudo yum install -y mailx
```

Test Mail command-:

```
$ echo "Mail test" | mail -s "Subject" youremail@domain.com
```

Answer (score -2):

#### Sending Simple Mail:

```
$ mail -s "test message from centos" recipient@example.com
hello from centos linux command line
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to finish

Comment: he is asking in on line command.