# Sending an e-mail using linux command

Tags: linux, shell, email

How to email the status of a database transaction

Scenario : "UPDATE xxx SET xxxx=1111 where yyy=111;

I need to trigger a mail the status whether the value got updated in db or not.How can i do it

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Sending+an+e-mail+using+linux+command

Comment: possible duplicate of [send mail from linux terminal in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318770/send-mail-from-linux-terminal-in-one-line)

Comment: well, that's actually two questions, post a separate question if the rest is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There is an way to do both in a single line command, using `mysql` and `mail` commands as follows,

```
mysql -D databasename -u username -p password -e "update xxx set xxxx= 1111 where yyy=111"|mail -s subject your@mail.com
```

Here is the **explanation** of above command:

For `mysql` command

`-D [database]` : this option is used for selecting database at MySQL.

`-u [username]` : this option is used for selecting username at MySQL.

`-p [password]` : this option is used for selecting password at MySQL.

For `mail` command

`-s [subject]`  : this option is used for subject string.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318770/send-mail-from-linux-terminal-in-one-line) for `mail` command.