# Git Pre Push Hook send email

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I want to **send email** to my other developer whenever i do the commit and before i push the commits to the server. I believe i have to use `pre-push` hook.

```
#!/bin/sh

GIT_DIR_="$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"
BRANCH="$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD))"

//How to send email to my other developer.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318770/send-mail-from-linux-terminal-in-one-line

Comment: It might be a little overkill to send a mail with every commit