# sending an email with C++ (Linux/Mac)

Tags: c++, linux, email

I was used to use Matlab, and for very long simulation I created a function which sent me an email whenever Matlab finished. It was a very easy Matlab function, you just had to add your email, password and the SMTP (I think).

Now, because of university stuff, I have to use C++ (I'm not very familiar with it, as you have probably guessed) but I can't find an equivalent way for sending an email to myself. 
I compile my .cpp in Terminal, using g++.

Can you please help me? I don't know if I miss some libraries or what.

Comment: Have you really tried anything? If yes, what? Do you get an error?

Comment: I guess you need to use an external system call or use a library for that, on linux there are many ways to send an email, you don't need to use pure C++ for that (if you want to keep it simple). So you only need to figure out how to send an email from the terminal with some linux tool (e.g. `sendmail`) and then how to execute a system call from c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in C++ it would be the best to go for some library like

1. [libquickmail](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/)
2. [vmime](https://www.vmime.org/about.html)

If it is ok for you to call some other program (like linux terminal program) go and check this stackoverflow answers [send-mail-from-linux-terminal-in-one-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318770/send-mail-from-linux-terminal-in-one-line)

Using the last method will leave with you with something like that (minimal example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    int status;
    status = system(R"(echo "this is the body" | mail -s "this is the subject" "to@address")");

    return 0;
}
```

R"()" is c++ [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) so you don't have to care about escape characters (but is available since C++11).
Here see the documentation for [system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) to check how it work.

Comment: Oh yes!! I think this will be fine!
Thank you so much!

Comment: So you can accept this answer and upvote if it was useful :)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use libquickmail, using my pc (Mac). I've installed both libquickmail and libcurl but I always get this error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64. Can the problem be in my g++ from terminal? There are many similar problem, each one with a different solution. On Monday I'm gonna try with linux and see if something changes.