# how to send url link using sendmail command

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

Am sending the mail with command

```
(
        echo "To:   $ml_address"
        echo 'From: Mxs <ml@gmail.com>'
        echo "Subject: Report"
        echo "mail body"
        echo "$file_content"
    ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

how to send url link using above command

Comment: This will help. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318770/send-mail-from-linux-terminal-in-one-line]

Comment: The immediate problem is that you need an empty line between the headers and the email body. But more fundamentally, probably don't try to create email messages by pasting together strings, especially if you are not familiar with the requirements. Simple small ASCII-only single-part messages will work fine, but the code will break as soon as you need accented characters, curly quotes, or binary attachments, or a number of other weird corner cases like lines which begin with the five characters `From ` (space) in the body.