# Postfix don't receive emails

Tags: mysql, email, debian, postfix-mta, dovecot

I have configured postfix from this tutorial:
http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-debian-wheezy

I can succesulfy send email but can't receive.

Informations from /var/log/mail.log
Oct 30 15:51:56 Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal postfix/lmtp[31594]: C9E97C40E7D: to=, relay=none, delay=0.1, delays=0.08/0.02/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.xxxxxx[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)

mailq info:

root@Debian-76-wheezy-64-minimal /home/vmail/xxxxx/admin # mailq
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
1AE0FC40E7F     1367 Thu Oct 30 15:53:53  yyyyyy@uuuuuu
 (connect to mail.precyl.com[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)
                                         admin@xxxxxxx

Anyone have idea how to fix it? I'm trying so hard and don't have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Go to /var/ and change the privileges of the folder /var/mail accordingly by right click on the folder and going to "Properties", then go to the "Permissions" tab; if you change everything to "Change and Delete files" will work for sure but change accordingly!

Answer (score -1):

Are you sending from an email client or direct from the server? If you are using a email client try to send it from the server using the terminal:

[How to send email from Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260858/how-to-send-email-from-terminal)

Check `/etc/postfix/main.cf` for "mynetworks" var. Maybe you are blocking for localhost use only.

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately from terminal it's the same error.