# How to reminds me when the program of R finished in Linux?

Tags: linux, r, terminal

I always use computer of campus to run R program. Every time, I always check it in terminal (I use `ssh` to connect to that computer) again and again to see whether the program is finished or not. Is there a way that the computer which is running my program can reminds me (e.g. send email to me) when the program is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a `BASH` script that runs your R task and send you Email after it finish.

to send Email in `bash` see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260923/1726419

Comment: how to realized sending email after it finishes? I know how to write a shell script to run my task and how to send email.

Comment: so the script will be somthing like: A.Run R. B.Send Mail.

Comment: @Ben does your R task auto close it's process after it finish?

Comment: Yes. The R tasks (I use paralllel in one computer) will auto closed.

Comment: I already write a shell script to run R programs in linux. But I have no idea how to send email after program finished.

Comment: Ok. so if you luanch the R task from bash script and after the task you write the mail command it should work.

Comment: The link in the answer shows how to send Email - just add this part after the R part