# How to create email form in zabbix and send email from dashboard?

Tags: forms, email, zabbix, sender

I want to create an email form in zabbix and call it from zabbix dashboard (e.g. on panel, where I have a list my scripts) and then send the email. How can I do it?
version zabbix 4.0

Answer (score 1):

In Zabbix 4.0 you can use a [Script](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/administration/scripts), but it cannot be a form: just a static command to send a predefine message through your CLI (see [How to send email from Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260858/how-to-send-email-from-terminal)).

In Zabbix 5.0 you can use a [Module](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/modules), basically adding whatever you want to the UI.

Also note that Zabbix is not meant for this. Mail notifications are meant be be sent after an Event triggers an Action.

Comment: Tnx for question! I will try to update Zabbix 4.0 and use Module.